# Connecting BLE Tags to Thingsboard Cloud

Tags: iot, thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

I'm looking for guidance the best way to connect Dewalt BLE Tags to ThingsBoard Cloud.
I currently have the following in place -
Lansitec Macro BLE beacons -> Tektelic macro gateway -> ThingsBoard Cloud.

Need to know how to connect the Dewalt BLE tags to the Beacons then to report into ThingsBoard.
I have the info for Dewalt tags.

I've read I may need an IOT gateway to do this but unsure.

I need to be able to have the BLE tags report to which BLE beacon they are attached too. I am using them for asset tracking.